Get count of id for each day and Group by date
Currently, I have a query that looks like this:
SELECT send_id, count(id) FROM `table1`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
GROUP BY send_id;

This returns a result that looks like this:
|   send_id   |   count(id)   |
-------------------------------
|    00123    |       32      |  
|    00234    |       12      | 
|    00567    |      100      | 
|    00890    |       07      | 
-------------------------------

I want to add the date and get the count for each send_id for each day.
I wrote this query:
SELECT DATE(date) as 'date', send_id, count(id) FROM `table1`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
GROUP BY date, send_id;    

I use DATE(date) because the column date is a datetime.  I don't need the time, just the date.
I am getting results that look like this:
|     date    |   send_id   |   count(id)   |
---------------------------------------------
| 2024-09-01  |    00123    |       03      |  
| 2024-09-01  |    00123    |       10      | 
| 2024-09-01  |    00567    |       20      | 
| 2024-09-01  |    00567    |       05      | 
---------------------------------------------

The results I was looking for should be like this:
|     date    |   send_id   |   count(id)   |
---------------------------------------------
| 2024-09-01  |    00123    |       13      |  
| 2024-09-01  |    00567    |       25      | 
---------------------------------------------

Because send_id had a total id count of 13 on 2024-09-01, but it's breaking it off into 2 rows.
The id is the auto_incremented field.
I think it's because of the datetime, but I'm not sure.
How can I fix the query so that it gets the id count of each send_id for each day?

could you please show some sample data for your expected output

@Sergey Forgive me.  I did specify how I wanted the results to look like above.  Was there something else you were looking for me to display?

Check out your GROUP BY. Shouldn't it be group by date(date), send_id?

if the advice above from Isolated does not help, it would be nice to see some sample data for send_id=00567/ 00123  Because for me your query looks quite OK

@Isolated - Man - How did I miss that?  I didn't think to put date(date) in the group by.  That seems to have solved my issue.

As always: If you ask SQL questions, please also post some example data (ie table defintion and table data) and explain your desired result based on that example data.

You can also use a different alias than the column name. GROUP BY prefers the column than the alias when they're the same.

Just adding comment as answer. Check out your GROUP BY, where you need to also group by date(date).
GROUP BY DATE(DATE), SEND_ID


When you use GROUP BY date it's grouping by the date column in the table, not the date alias that you assigned to DATE(date).
You can avoid this problem by using a different name for the alias:
SELECT DATE(date) AS txn_date, , send_id, count(id) 
FROM `table1`
WHERE date BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
GROUP BY txn_date, send_id;


I'd recommend a derived table, to make the date to DATE(date) conversion in advance, then GROUP BY its result. (Very handy trick to avoid repeating complex group by expressions.)
SELECT date, send_id, count(id)
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE(date) as 'date', send_id, id  FROM `table1`
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' AND '2024-09-30%'
) dt
GROUP BY date, send_id


Given you have datetime columns, this WHERE clause will perform so much better:
WHERE date >= '2024-09-01' AND date < '2024-10-01'

Thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, treating dates as strings is much slower and more error-prone than we'd like to believe. It's something to avoid.
Using the LIKE '2024-09-01%' expression forces the database to implicitly do this slower conversion from datetime to a string type for every row in the table, even rows that won't be used. And making this conversion means the converted values no longer match values used with any index you might have had, making the index worthless for this query.
Whenever possible you want to write your conditional expressions to avoid mutating the values stored in the table.
In the case of dates, this commonly means writing two expressions forming a half-open range with an exclusive upper bound for the day after the close of the range.
Put it all together like this:
SELECT DATE(date) as 'date', send_id, count(id)
FROM `table1`
WHERE date >= '2024-09-01' AND date < '2024-10-01'
GROUP BY DATE(DATE), SEND_ID

As a bonus, for month ranges like this you no longer have to worry about finding the correct last day of the month. Instead you will always use the first day of the month following.

Is the % in BETWEEN '2024-09-01%' actually a (LIKE) wildcard? I thought it was a typo.

@jarlh It's certainly what the OP intends it to be. But whether it works that way or not it's poor practice.

you can use try_cast to convert the data into date_type
SELECT 
    TRY_CAST(date AS DATE) AS date,
    send_id,
    COUNT(id) AS count_id
FROM table1
WHERE date BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'
GROUP BY TRY_CAST(date AS DATE), send_id


MySQL doesn't have TRY_CAST(), that's SQL-Server. DATE(date) is correct for MySQL.

Other than that, your answer is identical to @isolated's
